# Why I get attachFile(File) is undefined for the type MimeBodyPart?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I wanna attach some file to my email but I get this syntax error

```
     if (attachedFiles != null && attachedFiles.size() > 0) {
        for (File aFile : attachedFiles) {
        MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            try {


            attachPart.attachFile(aFile);
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }

                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            }
           }
```

Comment: *but I get this syntax error*: **which** error? Post the exact and complete error you get.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  The current version is 1.6.3.  The attachFile method was added in 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved My problem with adding mail1_4.jar
attach method was not supported in old versions